# PersonAccount fields in Page layouts missing!

Tags: person-accounts

We are using Person Accounts. I have created PersonAccounts record types, and Page Layouts under the personAccounts section in the setup menu. My profile can see the PersonAccount records.
When editing a PersonAccount Page Layout there are no Contact fields, or Person Account fields that are available to be placed into the layout. There is no personAddress fields, no personEmail, etc... Neither is there a tab to find them or a selection in the menu. 
I still have the Billing Address available, but I uploaded my data to the personAddress fields. I can find them in the API, but not the user interface. 
I've read the implementation notes and other instructions online and all of them mention that these fields should be readily available for selection like its a no brainer. Apparently, I don't have a brain, so could someone direct me to what I'm missing about person Account page layouts?

Comment: Can you check the Field Level Security of fields which are missing on Page Layout?

Comment: I checked them as well. Didn't see the fields there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_fields.htm&language=en

PLease refer to the above links for the fields which are available under the person account.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't tell me why none of the PersonAccount fields appear in the PersonAccount Page layouts when trying to put them into the page.

Comment: can you list the fields which are missing.

Comment: PersonEmail, PersonMailingStreet, PersonMailingCity, PersonMailingPostalCode, PersonMailingState, PersonMailingCountry

Comment: It looks like you have confused the Field API with Field Labels. THe ones you have mentioned are API names, and whereas in pagelayout editor you should be looking for field labels.  "PersonEmail" is nothing but the email field from the Account Object.

Comment: Yep! I think I was confused because people had not been using the personAccount and had been using the old fields, so when I added the fields into the page, there was nothing there. I can see the API name on custom fields, but not on standard fields, which contributed to the confusion. Thanks for responding.